# Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0), how to avoid?

Tags: java, sql, insert-update

> Java Code
>
> I have been trying to updated the selected row values but Im getting Parameter index out of bound exception. Any suggestions? the statement is correct, also can anyone explain in why it occurs?

```
public class Editbook extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            String booktitle = request.getParameter("booktitle");
            String author = request.getParameter("author");
            String category = request.getParameter("category");
            String pages = request.getParameter("pages");
            String desc = request.getParameter("description");
            String isbn = request.getParameter("isbn");

            Connection con = Logincheck.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("update books set title ='"+booktitle+"', author ='"+author+"', category ='"+category+"', pages ='"+pages+"', description ='"+desc+"' where isbn ='"+isbn+"'");

            ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(isbn));
            ps.setString(2, booktitle);
            ps.setString(3, author);
            ps.setString(4, category);
            ps.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(pages));
            ps.setString(6, desc);

            int i = ps.executeUpdate();
            out.println("updated");
            System.out.println(i + "updated");
        } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}

    }

}
```

Comment: You are mixing concatenation and sql param.

Answer (score 2):

In the `PreparedStatement`, you are directly putting the values of the parameters and not using any `?`. So when you write

```
 ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(isbn));
```

This statement is to replace the first occurrence of `?` with the specified value. But since there is no `?`, it gives Parameter index out of bound exception.

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating a `PreparedStatement` and supplying your parameters to it, it must be marked accordingly in your SQL. Right now you are concatenating a full SQL and then you can not supply any parameters to it as there are no parameters to supply. Instead each parameter is marked as a ? in your SQL.

Your code should be something in the lines of (note the order of the parameters):

```
Connection con = Logincheck.getConnection();
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("update books set title = ?, author = ?, category = ?, pages = ?, description = ? where isbn = ?");

ps.setString(1, booktitle);
ps.setString(2, author);
ps.setString(3, category);
ps.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(pages));
ps.setString(5, desc);
ps.setInt(6, Integer.parseInt(isbn));
```

EDIT: On another note. Using parameters the way I have posted here is much more preferred than concatenating a full SQL string as it will make your code less prone to SQL Code injection.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your HttpServletRequest has no parameters. So you can't access them here

```
String booktitle = request.getParameter("booktitle");
            String author = request.getParameter("author");
```

I would recommend to check if request contains parameters at first and then access them:

```
if (request.getParameterMap().containsKey("booktitle")) {
            String booktitle = request.getParameter("booktitle");
        }
```

And show how you build your post request.

Comment: [`getParameter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)) return `null` if the parameter does not exist.